# nodejs server gives bad request(400) errors. Why ?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs(0.12) and express (3.1.0). 
My server keeps on running perfectly for some times but after some times, it start giving 400 (bad requests) and keep it giving 400 for next all requests

```
message: "Error: Bad Request
at SendStream.error (/var/www/storehippo/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:145:16)
at SendStream.pipe (/var/www/storehippo/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:298:31)
at Object.static (/var/www/storehippo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:83:8)
at Object.handle (eval at eval at wrapHandle (/var/www/storehippo/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/connect.js:1:0))
at /var/www/storehippo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15
at /var/www/storehippo/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:157:28
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/storehippo/dist/dist_17-09-2016_10:20:03/app/index.js:252:5)
at Object.handle (eval at eval at wrapHandle (/var/www/storehippo/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/connect.js:1:0))
at /var/www/storehippo/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15
at /var/www/storehippo/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:157:28"
```

For fixing it, I have to restart my server and not able to find root cause of it.

How to find root cause and resolve it ?

Comment: You need to provide much more information than this.

Comment: Please provide some code for us to solve the issue.

Comment: @ravishankar Well? Did you solve it?

Comment: @rajeshpanwar Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633258/nodejs-server-gives-bad-request400-errors-why/39634977#39634977) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to update them if they need improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using Node 0.12 - currently the LTS version (recommended for all uses) is 4.5.0 and the Current version is 6.6.0 (6.x will become LTS next month). You may consider upgrading Node because you are using a very outdated version. The maintainence period of 0.12 will end in few months and then it will no longer get any updates, see: https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts_schedule

The Express module you use is also very outdated. The latest 3.x is I think 3.21.2 and the current version of Express is 4.14.0.

Now, if you want to find the problem then you should probably start from looking at the line 252 of `/var/www/storehippo/dist/dist_17-09-2016_10:20:03/app/index.js` because that seems to be the only line of your own code in that stack trace. The other lines seem to be all external modules, but it's also possible that the problem lies with one of those modules.

There may be a lot of reasons why your server behaves fine and then starts to misbehave - you may have some memory leak, some resources that are not freed and get exhausted after some time, you may change some state in your application that causes other requests to fail, etc.

Unfortunately you didn't include any info that would make it possible to help you with finding the problem.